# Problem with monitoring Glassfish with JConsole

Tags: java, glassfish, jmx

I have enabled JMX connection on remote Glassfish server and then I've restarted it. During starting server notified:

```
Standard JMX Clients (like JConsole) can connect to JMXServiceURL:
[service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://myserver:8686/jmxrmi] for domain management purposes.
```

Port 8686 is opened for connections.

But I can't connect to server with JConsole.. It says: Connection failed.

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to add -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=
in the JVM Options of the instance of GlassFish.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, JMX is using 8686 as the port for the RMI registry, but JConsole connects there only to find the port to use for the JMX server, which is dynamically allocated.  You might be running into an issue of having a firewall block access to this other port.  You could verify this by using a remote desktop program to connect to the server, and then run JConsole locally (on the server).  If it connects, then I bet this is your issue.

Hope this helps...

Comment: No, the firewall is disabled on this machine. If you are interesting the full discussion of the issue and more details are here http://forums.java.net/jive/thread.jspa?messageID=361607
It is still unresolved.

Answer (score 0):

on windows 7 I have experienced similar problems and the solution was to change address on jmx-connector  to 127.0.0.1 in domain.xml